# How to use a column as a key to pivot columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, string-aggregation

I am trying to pivot a table and aggregate some sub-categories. However, when aggregating, the sub-categories aren't joining properly.

**Example Table**

```
| category | categorySub |
|----------|-------------|
| cat-1    | sub-1       |
| cat-1    | sub-2       |
| cat-1    | sub-3       |
| cat-2    | sub-4       |
| cat-2    | sub-5       |
```

**Actual Output**

```
| category | categorySub                               |
|----------|-------------------------------------------|
| cat-1    | ["sub-1","sub-2","sub-3","sub-4","sub-5"] |
| cat-2    | ["sub-1","sub-2","sub-3","sub-4","sub-5"] |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| category | categorySub               |
|----------|---------------------------|
| cat-1    | ["sub-1","sub-2","sub-3"] |
| cat-2    | ["sub-4","sub-5"]         |
```

**Query**

```
select 
[categoryMain] = [category],
[categorySub] = '["' + (select string_agg(categorySub, '","') from someTable where [categoryMain] = [category]) + '"]'
from someTable
group by [category]
```

How can I reference [category] or its alias to pare down the string aggregation?

Comment: you shouldn't be using a sub query. just use string_agg directly

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in `STRING_AGG` itself

```
DECLARE @T Table(
cat Varchar(max),
SUB varchar(max))

Insert into @T Values ('cat-1','sub-1')
Insert into @T Values ('cat-1','sub-2')
Insert into @T Values ('cat-1','sub-3')
Insert into @T Values ('cat-2','sub-4')
Insert into @T Values ('cat-2','sub-5')

SELECT CAT AS CATEGORYMAIN, '["' + STRING_AGG(SUB, '","')+ '"]' AS SUB 
FROM @T GROUP BY [CAT]
```

Comment: Much simpler as `SELECT CAT AS CATEGORYMAIN, '["' + STRING_AGG(SUB, '","')+ '"]' AS SUB FROM @T GROUP BY [CAT]`

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggested, we can use `string_agg` directly like:

```
select 
[categoryMain] = [category],
[categorySub] = '["' + (select string_agg(categorySub, '","') + '"]'
from someTable
group by [category]
```

Comment: And you don't need the `select` either, `'["' +  string_agg(categorySub, '","' + '"]'` should work